# PHP Remove same value of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have arrays and these arrays have same values and I want to remove the same values and print the different values.

Arrays:

```
Array(
    [0] => Likes
    [7] => Frind
    [8] => USA
)
Array(
    [0] => USA
    [5] => Lools
)
Array(
    [6] => USA
    [12] => Awesome
)
```

I need to like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Likes
    [7] => Frind
    [8] => USA
    [5] => Lools
    [12] => Awesome
)
```

Comment: do the keys of the arrays matter?

Comment: @murtho no don't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$array1 = ['likes', 'friends', 'USA']
$array2 = ['USA', 'lools']
$array3 = ['USA', 'Awesome']

$temp_array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
$final_array = array_unique(array_merge($temp_array, $array2));
```

Comment: this arrays automatically created my friend and cant to save this to separate arrays ...!

Comment: If it so pass them directly in array merge parameter there is no need to create an additional variable $temp_arrray

Comment: Can you give me example please !

Comment: How are you generating the arrays?

Comment: do it like this. make a $final_array  = [] and keep on updating in the foreach loop by $final_array = array_unique(array_merge($final_array, $finalarrays))

Comment: keep $final_array outside foreach loop and print also outside for each loop

Comment: Updated my friend but not work and just show me the one array !

Comment: could you post the output as well

Comment: use `["name"]` along with `$finalarrays` in the array_merge statement as you are only interested that part of the associative array

Answer (score 3):

First you should merge the arrays:

```
$merged = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Then you can use `array_unique` method

```
$unique_array = array_unique($merged);
```

Comment: You can pass every arrays to the `array_merge` method.